# Retrieve the end position of the caret in the TextBox to put the Caret in the next TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, position, caret

How do I find the end position of the Caret in a WPF textbox so I can`t move right anymore with the caret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the CaretIndex look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888907/set-the-caret-cursor-position-to-the-end-of-the-string-value-wpf-textbox).

However, if you are looking to jump to the next TextBox under certain conditions check out the following sample.  Here I use the TextBox property MaxLength and the KeyUp event to jump to the next TextBox when one is completed.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBox Text="" MaxLength="3" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" >
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="" MaxLength="3" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp">
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="" MaxLength="4" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp">
        </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is the KeyUp event from the code-behind:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
   if (( tb != null ) && (tb.Text.Length >= tb.MaxLength))
   {
      int nextIndex = 0;
      var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tb);
      int items = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
      for( int index = 0; index < items; ++index )
      {
         TextBox child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, index) as TextBox;
         if ((child != null) && ( child == tb ))
         {
            nextIndex = index + 1;
            if (nextIndex >= items) nextIndex = 0;
            break;
         }
      }

      TextBox nextControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, nextIndex) as TextBox;
      if (nextControl != null)
      {
         nextControl.Focus();
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
After reading the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888958/can-i-navigate-into-and-out-of-a-wpf-combo-box-using-arrow-keys-instead-of-tab/3892441#3892441)  I modified the TextBox_KeyUp as follows:

```
  private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
     Action<FocusNavigationDirection> moveFocus = focusDirection =>
     {
        e.Handled = true;
        var request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);
        var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
        if (focusedElement != null)
           focusedElement.MoveFocus(request);
     };

     TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
     if ((tb != null) && (tb.Text.Length >= tb.MaxLength))
     {
        moveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Zamboni, your code Action... is nice. Are these anonymous methods?