# XAML: move the cursor in textbox automatically

Tags: wpf, xaml

I dont know if this works but is there any chance to move the cursor inside a `Textbox` automaticaly for one position(1 space bar click). For example: 
I run the application and the cursor inside the `Textbox` moves automatically for one space bar

my textbox:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="Searchbox_TextChanged" x:Name="Testing" Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SearchSmthg, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Controls:TextboxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Search ..."/>
```

Comment: use `CaretIndex`, e.g. `<TextBox Text="123" CaretIndex="1" />`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2892988/352101

Comment: It is a bit unclear, do you want to move the cursor in a predefined string or do you want to insert a space in the textbox?

Comment: Sorry, i want to insert a space, but without clicking the space bar

Comment: Do you want to have a space in the actual text? Or just some visual padding? If you just want Padding use `Padding="3,0,0,0"`

Answer (score 0):

use [`CaretIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892988/352101) and `FocusManager`:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Focustext}">
            <TextBox x:Name="Focustext" Text=" " CaretIndex="1" MaxHeight="25"  />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**Edit:** add a `GotFocus` event handler and set `CaretIndex=1` there

*XAML:*

```
<TextBox GotFocus="Testing_GotFocus"
```

*Code Behind:*

```
private void Testing_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //make sure your Textbox is not empty..
            Testing.CaretIndex = 1;
        }
```